# Is it smart thing to create html string on server side and append it on client side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I need to transfer a large amount of data from server to client and then, with JavaScript (jQuery) generate a lot of tables, `div`s and other know and unknown html elements .

When I was trying to generate those tables and `div`s on client side a had a couple of for loops and I was creating and appending elements on the fly.

I soon discovered that it takes a lot of time to generate all those elements and show them so I generate HTML on server side with `HtmlTextWriter` then I convert it `ToString()` and append that string on client side.

It is much faster but it is "seljacki" as we would call it in my language (the closest translation is "not elegant solution").

So I wanted to ask does anyone have some more elegant solution to suggest and is this method that I'm using completely wrong or it could pass?

Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't show your code here, but I'd guess that in your loop you are repeatedly appending rows to a table or whatnot as you iterate through the results. If so, the bottleneck is not actually generating the HTML but redrawing the content each iteration. Try assembling the entire HTML to add in memory first, then use a single `append()` or `html()` call to update the document.

Comment: Yes, this is most perfect solution. Most probably in your code you call each time some hard function, that works with DOM. Just try to profile your code in firebug or chrome tools.

Comment: Actualy I did. for example when I'm creating <td> elemnts i was doing something like :
var tr = $("<tr></tr>");
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
var td = $("<td></td>").text(data[i].Text);
tr.append(td);
}
But now i generate entire html (but on server side) and append it, and that is what i was asking, is it ok to do that on server like that or should i create it on client side? :)

Comment: Well you can, and lots of people do that. I don't like generating HTML fragments on a web service for several reasons: it's slower than sending data-only using JSON, it can make it more difficult to make changes to the site, and in many server-side technologies which predate AJAX it is a bit awkward to generate a fragment. If you generate a specific HTML layout for a particular page using a language like C#, it is hard for someone else down the road to look at a method, figure out the output and make changes. Using JS moves the problem, but I'd argue it is a more appropriate place for it.

Answer (score 0):

I would continue to pass the data to the client side and create the html. I've just started playing around with [jQuery templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) and so far they are awesome. Since it is obviously going to be a little slower creating the elements on the client side why not just create and/or load them as needed. The user can only see so much at a time so why make them wait for something they may never see.